# How do I select max value from 3 nullable datetime columns in sql / Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, max

I know about the regular use of Max in Linq and how that translates to Sql. e.g.:

```
var maxReservationID = db.reservations.Select(r => r.ReservationID).Max();
```

translates roughly to:

```
select max(reservationId) 
from reservations
```

But I can't see if or how the following SQL use of max (from 2008 onwards) can be written in Linq (for entity framework).

```
SELECT ReservationId, (select Max(v) 
FROM (VALUES (datecol1), (datecol2), (datecol3)) AS value(v)) as maxDate
FROM reservations
```

Reason: I need to compare and get the largest of 3 nullable date columns and the expression is getting huge so looking for ways to simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
var reservationMaxes = db.reservations
    .Select(r => new {
        Id = r.ReservationID,
        // other properties etc
        Max = new[] { r.datecol1, r.datecol2, r.datecol3 }.Max() // <-- the trick
    }).ToList();
```

Makes for some weird SQL (nested `unions` and `case when`) but works just fine (YMMV).

On a somewhat related note, you can "merge" multiple math queries (`collection.Max(...)`, `collection.Count(...)`) using a `.GroupBy` "hack" -- https://damieng.com/blog/2014/09/04/optimizing-sum-count-min-max-and-average-with-linq

So that what would normally be 3 SQL calls:

```
IQueryable<T> items;
var scoreHigh = items.Max(i => i.OverallScore); // #1
var soldHigh = items.Max(i => i.Sold); // #2
var count = items.Count();  // #3
```

is instead one call (and seems to be faster):

```
 var maths = items.GroupBy(i => 1).Select(g => new {
    Score = g.Max(i => i.OverallScore),
    Sold = g.Max(i => i.Sold),
    Count = g.Count()
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Also has the added benefit of not throwing an exception when there would be nothing in the result set, and instead returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do it directly with EF would be using ternary operators ( a ? b : c) to simulate a 'CASE WHEN'... But it will be unreadable for such a simple thing.

I would either :

- Create a SQL View, with the query you posted (the faster method) and then call it with EF.
- Retrieve all the results and then, for each item compute the resulting Max value.

Comment: They would rather use EF and not care about the quality of the SQL code generated, it seems.